# Algorithms for interval partitioning with possible delay

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Interval partitioning is a variant of interval scheduling problems. This problem requires us to schedule all the jobs and find the minimum number of machines for doing the jobs.

One of the most popular solution is to use greedy algorithm. The greedy algorithm firstly sorts all the jobs by their starting time and we start scheduling jobs one-by-one.

However, the disadvantage of this greedy algorithm is that the schedule is very tight and when there is a delay in a job, the next job may face a conflict and require rescheduling.

The problem is: is there an algorithm that can handle interval partitioning with delay and that rescheduling is expensive and should be avoided?

I have tried searching but I can only find greedy algorithm which cannot deal with delays.

Comment: I think you need to specify what exactly delay means. When is it possible to get precise information about delays(are they known beforehand or do they appear dynamically)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The delays appear dynamically but we just want to be able to handle to some degrees of delays. Let say the delay is in a range of [0, threshold).

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "rescheduling is expensive and should be avoided". Are we just adding a safety factor to all the job lengths? Is there an expected cost function being minimized? Are some jobs more likely to have delays than others? Are we minimizing the worst case time where everything goes wrong?